# Change Maven CheckStyle configuration

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I am using Maven an Checkstyle to check my code for quality. Though there are things I'd like to turn off in CheckStyle.

There is a module taking care on trailing spaces. The comment it gives is:

```
Line has trailing spaces.
```

Now I assume the module taking care on that is called RegexpSingleline and I'd like to turn it off. I already tried by uncommenting the file in `./myproject/target/checkstyle-checker.xml`, but when I run `mvn site` this file is automatically generated again and my changes in it vanish.

How would I turn this moule off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a copy of the `checkstyle-checker.xml` document and store it outside `/target` (as this directory will be overridden in the build!). Then, in your `pom.xml` you can specify this location in the checkstyle plugin configuration (see: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html)

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>..your version of the plugin..</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>..your location../checkstyle-checker.xml</configLocation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```